# DHCP-DHCP Relay Agent

Tags: dhcp

I am using the Ubuntu 18.04.
For the seek of an enterprise client i would like to use my server as a DHCP server and as a DHCP Relay Agent. I am not sure if this is a possible solution.
I know that this is feasible with Cisco technology and with Mikrotik, but as a newbie in this i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are multiple choices.

One option is to you use `dhcrelay` from ISC. As command:

```
#IPv4
dhcrelay -4 --no-pid -l eth1 -u eth2
#IPv6
dhcrelay -6 --no-pid -l eth1 -u eth2
```

`-l` lower interface (listening for requests), `-u` upper interface relaying request to other DHCP.

But you don't have launch that way, the package contain services

1. Install its package

   ```
   sudo apt install isc-dhcp-relay
   ```
2. Copy the needed service file or both:

   ```
   /lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-relay.service
   /lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-relay6.service
   ```

   To

   ```
   /etc/systemd/system/
   ```
3. Edit them and put the network interfaces.
4. Start the service, similar to

   ```
   sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-relay
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-relay6
   ```

References:

- [`man dhcrelay`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/dhcrelay.8.html)